# Trouble With tabBarControllers

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

These are the steps I've taken in creating a TabBarController.

1. Created 3 view controllers, Given their Class Names in Storyboard and embedded them in TabBarController.
   (Doubt: Do we have to give a class name to TabBarController also?)
2. I wanted to implement tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController: method of its delegate but have no clue WHERE exactly to do it.
   Also can we conform the protocol to the tabBarController itself instead of creating a delegate object explicitly?How?

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have create new subclass of UITabBarController and set this class in storyboard as well.and conform class to UITabBarControllerDelegate.

In  viewDidLoad method write

```
 self.delegate=self;
```

And implement Delegate method

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0) {

    }

    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 1) {

    }
    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 2) {

    }
    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 3) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Worked great! Is there a way to conform to the delegate protocol in the storyboard by ctrl+clicking somewhere instead of doing it programmatically?

Comment: i think no, if you try to do that possibility of crashes while loading tab bar controller.

Comment: If you right click the yellow box on top of the scene in storyboard you can see the "reference outlets" where we connect the data source and delegate.
I usually use it for tableview protocols but for tab bar the ctrl-clicking is not working! :(